Migrating to TZ aware datetime in Django, PostgreSQL timestamp
I use Django ORM to access PostgreSQl data. Database is relatively big ~100 tables, some with dozens of millions of records. I'm switching from Django 4.2 to Django 5.0, which has USE_TZ = True by default and I want to keep it that way, so after the migration - hopefully there won't be any naive datetimes in my system.
I have models like:
class MyExistingModel(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

...and what I'm witnessing for the most of my models is the following:
In [6]: mem = MyExistingModel.objects.create(name="new record")

In [7]: mem.date_created
Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 23, 6, 15, 25, 885356, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

In [8]: MyExistingModel.objects.get(name="new record").date_created
Out[8]: datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 23, 1, 15, 25, 885356)

Same record, same field - two different datetime formats: aware vs naive. Whenever those two are mixed I'm of course getting an error like:
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
This is a big problem as I can hardly control every single place where DateTimeField is used.
It seems that the reason behind this is the fact that date_created in my PostgreSQL, which was created by Django long time ago, is of timestamp without time zone. That's what I'm seeing with DB editor. This isn't the case for every single table though. There are tables where some fields are of timestamp with time zone type. I guess that depends of which version of Django was used to create those tables/fields. Makes sense?
Anyways, I tried migrating manually one field and then I got a consistent behaviour: always TZ aware timestamps.
Question:
Do I really need to go migrate every table in the system in order to have a clean situation here? Two problems: possibly long downtime and error prone operation since I need to be pretty careful in locating only those DateTimeField fields that are really without time zone.

I see no way around it. Your data has to be updated somehow. You don’t need to create a downtime because you can write a database script to do the update.

Sure, I'll use a database script, but the thing is that TZ-aware timestamps will need a new version of the software, which cannot go live until all records are updated, as it would introduce inconsistencies.
